# Add Overlay color to every element on page in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to add an overlay color to every element on an arbitrary html page and have it be constantly colored. So that when I hover the element I can remove the overlay, thereby highlighting the hovered element, like so:

[image: Highlighted element]

I was hoping I'd be able to do something like this:

```
* {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

*:after {
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

But you just end up with nested elements having multiple overlays over them, so it doesn't look so clean. Ends up looking more like this:

[image: nested overlay]

The only other alternative I can think of is some kind of overlay element that covers the entire page, then when you hover an element it adds some sort of anti-overlay element over it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: May i ask rather than doing this overlay stuff why don't you set the background color and text color to a shade and then on hover make that element's color bright?

Comment: Could you not create a custom css class and add it to your top level elements?

Comment: rather than have an overlay, why not just lighten the background colour of the element that is hovered - that's all your first image seems to be doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that dealing with nested elements is possible with CSS alone.

Here is an example of how I might tackle this problem. You could convert this to vanilla JS if you wish.

There are a few test cases included but this is a very simple example. Your results may vary.

```js
$('*').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();  
    
    if ($(this).is('body')) return; /* prevent flicker */
    
    $('*').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
})

$('*').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
})
```

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

body:hover:after {
  display: none;
}

.hovered {
  outline: 1px dashed cyan;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000vh rgba(0, 0, 0, .25); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1>
  Lorem ipsum
  </h1>
  
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ac posuere dolor. Vivamus urna neque, venenatis vitae mauris non, vehicula tristique magna. Ut sed metus sed ex interdum fermentum.
  
    <a href="#">
      A nested link
    </a>
   
  </p>
  
  <p>
    Some text with an image nested within a paragraph, which is nested within a div.
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </p>
  
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item
      <ul>
        <li>Nested list item</li>
        <li>Nested list item</li>
        <li>Nested list item</li>
        <li>Nested list item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is amazing, exactly what I was looking for. How would you go about adding a transition to this so the hover is a bit less jarring? I tried adding `transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;` to the `hovered` class but that didn't work.

Comment: Transitions should work. You could also add `.hovered:hover` to adjust the in/out transition timing. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/djck8w1q/1/

Comment: thank you @Turnip
your idea about box-shadow was great

Answer (score 4):

You can add one overlay with a big z-index and once you hover an element you increase its z-index to move it above:

```css
body:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 999;
  pointer-events: none;/* This will do all the magic !*/
}

body *:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>tile</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id rhoncus arcu. Phasellus venenatis ex nulla, nec feugiat nibh sodales at. Pellentesque vehicula eu arcu at varius</p>

<div>
  <h2>another title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id rhoncus arcu. Phasellus venenatis ex nulla, nec feugiat nibh sodales at. Pellentesque vehicula eu arcu at varius</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This would only work for a document where every element was a child of body. Adding even one level of nesting, a div around the content for example, would break it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try this solution:

1. Create parent with class 'overlay-parent'.
2. Your elements, that can have overlay, should be in one level under new parent.
3. in CSS:

```
.overlay-parent > * { // Affect every direct child element of this parent
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay-parent > *::after {
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section, header {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}

section:hover .overlay::before, header:hover .overlay::before{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
            This is a primary alert—check it out!
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
            This is a secondary alert—check it out!
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            This is a success alert—check it out!
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            This is a danger alert—check it out!
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            This is a warning alert—check it out!
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
            This is a info alert—check it out!
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
            This is a light alert—check it out!
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
            This is a dark alert—check it out!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a layout just to show you the effect. Add styles of `.overlay` within the section, you want to use the effect. Hope it'll help